# Proving the product of four consecutive odd integers is always 16 less than a square number.

Tags: number-theory

Show that the product of four consecutive odd integers is 16 less than a square.

For the first part I first did
$n=p(p+2)(p+4)(p+6)
=(p^2+6p)(p^2+6p+8).$
I know that you are supposed to rearrange this to give an equation in the form $(ap^2+bp+c)^2$, but I'm not sure how to. Also, once we get to that point, how do we prove it has to be odd numbers?

NOTE: I do not know how to edit Math LaTeX so I was hoping someone could edit my post for me. Thanks

Comment: Personally, I like writing it as $(p-4)(p-2)(p+2)(p+4)$, as it simplifies to $p^4-20p^2+64$

Comment: It seems like this holds for even as well as odd numbers. Just take the product you wrote down and add $16$, and you get $p^4+12p^3+44p^2+48p+16$. Then I looked at $(p^2+bp+4)^2$ and fiddled around in Wolfram until I found that $b=6$ got that same expression.

Comment: See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) about how to use MathJax.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let those consecutive odd integers be $2p-3 , 2p-1 , 2p+1, 2p+3$. Then their product is:
$(2p-3)(2p+3)(2p-1)(2p+1)=(4p^2-9)(4p^2-1)=16p^4-40p^2+9$
Next step is to notice that $16p^4-40p^2+9+16=16p^4-40p^2+25=(4p^2-5)^2$

Comment: I think you mean to have 16p^4 but otherwise this was really helpful

Comment: Yeah, my bad -> $(4p^2)^2=16p^4$. All corrected

Answer (score 3):

The middle number is $p+3 =: m_1$.

$$n = p(p+2)(p+4)(p+6) = p(p+6)(p+2)(p+4)
  = (m_1-3)(m_1+3)(m_1-1)(m_1+1)
  = (m_1^2-3^2)(m_1^2-1^2)
  = (m_1^2-9)(m_1^2-1)$$

Now, with a new "middle number" $m_2 := m_1^2-5$, we get

$$n = (m_2-4)(m_2+4) = m_2^2-16
  = (m_1^2-5)^2-16
  = ((p+3)^2-5)^2-16$$

So indeed $n+16$ is a square number, no matter whether $p$ is odd or not.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to start with the middle number, call it $k$. Then the four consecutive odd integers are $k-3,k-1,k+1,k+3$.

Multiply the outer two: $(k-3)(k+3)=k^2-9$

Multiply the inner two: $(k-1)(k+1)=k^2-1$

Multiply the two products: $(k^2-9)(k^2-1)=k^4-10k^2+9$

Now add $16$ to get $k^4-10k^2+25=(k^2-5)^2$

Comment: Would you just set k to 2k to prove its odd

Comment: You could do that, but the math works for any $k$ whether odd or even. So if it works in all cases, it works when $k=2m$. Avoiding all those powers of $2$ that appear makes the last identity easier to perceive. For purposes of giving an answer, you could just preface the proof with the statement "$k$ is even."

Comment: Got it thanks very much